# Pf kernel on ssd is it worth it (Ubuntu 13.04)

Tags: 13.04, kernel, ssd

Has anyone tried the pf kernel on an ssd in ubuntu? Is it going bring more performance in terms of reading and writing to ssds?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the [BFQ page](http://algo.ing.unimo.it/people/paolo/disk_sched/), that IO scheduler has lower latency (than cfq noop deadline and android-only sio) and identical throughput on SSDs.  The kernel is also more recent than the 13.04 default, always a plus for performance and functionality.

Comment: Isn't low latency only for BFS, I/O schedulers have that too?

Answer (score 0):

I have installed pf-kernel 3.19.0-pf3 compiled for Ubuntu and my PC is working like a charm with no delay in any application I could use, including video rendering of MKV files that struggle my graphic card to the limit. Perfect.
Pk-kernel is being compiled for Ubuntu for a while and it may be downloaded in: ftp://big-bum.uni.cx/pf-kernel/i386/